# Perl one liner to convert from shiftjis to utf8

Tags: perl, utf-8, shift-jis

I am trying the following one liner to convert a file from shiftjis encoding to utf-8 and its not working.  Any helpful smart people available?

```
perl -i.bak -e 'use utf8; use Encode qw(decode encode);  my $ustr = Encode::decode("shiftjis",$_); my $val = Encode::encode("utf-8",$ustr);  print "$val";' filename
```

I am pretty new to code pages and the web seems rife with all sorts of complexities on the subject.  I just want a one liner.  The input file and the output file appear to be the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? With 6.3K rep you should know by know to include that in your post.

Comment: The input file and the output file are the same.

Comment: I swear this will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `-n` switch, which will iterate over each line of input, loading one line at a time into `$_` and executing the code provided in the `-e` argument.

More concisely, you could write your program like

```
perl -MEncode -pi.bak -e '$_=encode("utf-8",decode("shiftjis",$_))' filename
```

Comment: Thanks been a long day!

Comment: `perl -MEncode=from_to -i.bak -pe'from_to $_, "shiftjis", "utf-8"' filename`

Answer (score 2):

Perl is an odd choice for this, given that there's already a standard utility for doing it:

```
iconv -f shift-jis -t utf-8 filename
```

Of course, that doesn't easily let you edit a file in-place, but there's also `recode` which is likewise installed on my system somehow :)...

```
recode shift-jis..utf-8 filename
```

Or use moreutils:

```
iconv -f shift-jis -t utf-8 filename | sponge filename
```

Hmm.  Seems like TMTOWTDI.

Comment: sometimes better than iconv: http://p3rl.org/piconv (comes with Perl)  `piconv -f shift-jis -t utf-8 filename`

Comment: @daxim wow, and i just learned of `psed` recently too.  perl apparently ships with an entire unix base system!